# JDK JRE upgrade causing issue

Tags: tomcat, tomcat6, java, java-7

I had a server running with `jdk1.5.0_16` and `jre1.6.0_03`. and was using tomcat 6.0 to deploy application and use window services to start stop tomcat.

Now, I have uninstalled both and installed latest `JRE(7u3)` and `JDK(7u3)` and have also updated `JAVA_HOME` and `PATH` to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03` and `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\bin` respectively

but now when i restart my tomcat server i get following error:-

```
---------------------------
Services
---------------------------
Windows could not start the Apache Tomcat on Local Computer. For more information, review the System Event Log. If this is a non-Microsoft service, contact the service vendor, and refer to service-specific error code 0.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

what m i missing? I havent changed anything in tomcat at all.

**EDIT:** getting following error in jakarta_service logs

```
 Failed creating java C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.5.0_16\bin\client\jvm.dll
[2012-02-27 18:00:12] [1260 prunsrv.c] [error] ServiceStart returned 1
```

Comment: Have you checked Tomcat's log file for error output?

Comment: Tomcat 6 ***may*** not work with Java 7. There have been other threads on SO about this very same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the solution..

`Tomcat6w.exe` had some configration paths and had jvm.dll path directly given there and it was fully hardcoded that was causing the issue

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your Tomcat service is set up with a hardcoded java-home value. Try running the following in a command-prompt (you will have to open it using "Run as administrator" if on vista/win7/server2008).

```
<path to your tomcat installation>\bin\tomcat7.exe //US//<name of your tomcat service> --JavaHome=%JAVA_HOME%
```

Name of the service can differ, but it's probably something like "Tomcat6" if you did a standard installation. If not, check in windows services to find out.

Comment: already tried.. it flashes the screen once and nothing happens

Comment: So, what are you seeing in the logs? Like "<catalina base>\logs\commons-daemon.<date>.log", "<catalina base>\logs\tomcat6-stderr.<date>.log", "<catalina base>\logs\tomcat6-stdout.<date>.log" or the windows event log.

Comment: As you can see in the jakarta_service log, your service is attempting to run tomcat using your old java 5 installation (C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.5.0_16\bin\client\jvm.dll). Check again that you have set JAVA_HOME correctly (for all users, not just your console user).

Comment: JAVA_HOME is set to correct location... the issue i saw is with CATALINA_HOME it was set to some other copy of tomcat... but updating it to my tomcat also doesnt helps...

Comment: Well, from the error in the error in the log it's clear that the service is attempting to still use your old java installation. So, either you have an incorrect JAVA_HOME or the service is incorrectly configured. You could try to delete the service and re-create it.

Answer (score 0):

I think your Environmental Variable for Tomcat CATALINA_HOME may not be set.Set the variable CATALINA_HOME to the Tomcat installed folder.After setting the Environmental Variable ,try the following command for starting the tomcat:

*%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\startup*

check the following link for more details .

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-4.1-doc/RUNNING.txt

Comment: update question... the tomcat was working fine with old JDK and JRE